# QGraphicsScene Is not performing proper hit detection

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I am having an issue where my `QGraphicsItem` is not alway performing proper hit detection with the mouse. I have subclassed `QGrahicsItem` and have overridden the `shape()` method. My `shape()` method calculates a polygon that surrounds the line. my `boudingRect()` function calculates a box that completely encloses the line. I have attached two screenshots. The first show the line highlighted in blue, indicating the hover event was fired. The second show the mouse moved just slightly to the right, but still well within the `shape()` and `boundingRect()` but the hover event did not fire. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

I should also note that if I move the endpoints of the line, the hit detection usually starts working normally. It seems somewhat random as to when it breaks.

Note: The polygon surrounding the line is the `shape()` and the rectangle around that is the `boundingRect()`
[image: Hover event fired.]

[image: Hover event not fired.]

**Update**
It seems that this must be a problem with the `boundingRect()`, as i zoom in to a non-working/partially-working line. The line will suddently disappear as if it's boundingRect() is no longer in the viewport, however, this is very obviously not the case as just before it disappears the bounding rect is visible.

Comment: Without code, we could only guess as to what the problem is. As you have rightly noted, collision is handled by both the boundingRect() and shape() functions of a QGraphicsItem, so the problem is likely to be there. Check that they return the local coordinates for the items. You could draw the boundingRect in the items' paint functions to show what exactly is being returned.

Comment: What you see on the screenshots is the drawn shape() and boundingRect() functions.

Comment: What about the boundingRect for the node, which the lines connect? Could this be wrong and causing an issue?

Comment: I have checked that. It is correct.